# ¿Cómo puedo convertir una respuesta de API en objetos de cualquier tipo en Kotlin usando Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room, dao

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con alrededor de **100 tablas diferentes** en una base de datos manejada con Room.

Esta aplicación debe buscar periódicamente en el servidor posibles cambios en **cualquiera de esas 100 tablas** a partir de una fecha determinada. Para ello, usando `WorkManager` se lanza periódicamente una solicitud a la API mediante Retrofit. Todo eso funciona perfectamente.

Mi idea es recibir esa respuesta y mapearla a un objeto llamado `Crud`, para luego hacer la operación correspondiente con cada tabla, **sin importar qué tablas haya en ese momento ni qué operación se requiera hacer en ellas (crear, leer, actualizar, eliminar)**, usando para ello una interfaz `BaseDao`.

Este es un ejemplo de respuesta, tal y como tengo diseñada la API ahora mismo:

```
{
  "haveData":true,
  "crud":[
    {
      "LHPsalmodyJoin":{
        "create":[
          {
            "groupID":100030203,
            "theType":1,
            "crud":"c"
          },
          {
            "groupID":102030206,
            "theType":0,
            "crud":"c"
          }
        ],
        "update":[
          {
            "groupID":100030203,
            "theType":1,
            "crud":"c"
          }
        ]
      },
      "LHPatristic":{
        "update":[
          {
            "groupID":108002301,
            "crud":"u"
          }
        ],
        "delete":[
          {
            "groupID":108001801,
            "crud":"d"
          },
          {
            "groupID":108001901,
            "crud":"d"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Como se puede ver:

- en la tabla **`LHPsalmodyJoin`** se deben **insertar `2` filas** y se debe **actualizar `1` fila**.
- en la tabla **`LHPatristic`** se debe **actualizar `1` fila** y se deben **eliminar `2` filas**.

Esta es la clase `Crud` a la que se asigna esta respuesta API:

```
class Crud {
    val lastUpdate: String = ""
    val haveData = false
    val crud: List<Any> = emptyList()

    //Iterar la propiedad crud 
    //llamando el método correspondiente de BaseDao
    //pasando para el parámetro T el tipo de objeto que sea
}
```

En **`BaseDao`** tengo lo siguiente:

```
interface BaseDao<T> {

    @Insert
    fun insert(obj: T)

    @Insert
    fun insert(vararg obj: T)

    @Update
    fun update(obj: T)

    @Insert
    fun update(vararg obj: T)

    @Delete
    fun delete(obj: T)

    @Insert
    fun delete(vararg obj: T)
}
```

#### El problema

Mi problema es que **la respuesta no se asigna a objetos de ningún tipo**.

En lugar de asignarse a objetos de tipo `LHPsalmodyJoin` y `LHPatristic` para este caso, se asigna a un objeto `LinkedTreeMap`, como pueden ver en esta imagen del inspector:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo asignar esta respuesta a sus respectivos objetos para pasarla al método `BaseDao` correspondiente sabiendo que no sé de antemano de cuáles de las 100 tablas habrá datos para crear, actualizar o borrar?

Aclaro que aunque hablo de un CRUD, para este caso no me interesa la lectura de datos, sino simplemente su creación, actualización o eliminación.